# Matplotlib multiple scatter subplots - reduce svg file size

Tags: matplotlib, svg, scatter-plot, subplot, inkscape

I generated a plot in Matplotlib which consists of 50 subplots. In each of these subplots I have a scatterplot with about 3000 datapoints. I'm doing this, because I just want to have an overview of the different scatter plots in a document I'm working on.

This also works so far and looks nice, but the problem is obviously that the SVG file that I'm getting is really big (about 15 MB). And Word just can't handle such a big SVG file.

So my question: is there a way to optimize this SVG file? A lot of my datapoints in the scatter plots are overlapping each other, so I guess it should be possible remove many "invisible" ones of them without changing the visible output. (so something like this in illustrator seems to be what I want to do: [Link](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12968/how-to-keep-only-the-visible-parts-of-the-every-object-path-of-a-svg-image-like)) Is it also possible to do something like this in Inkscape? Or even directly in Matplotlib?

I know that I can just produce a PNG file, but I would prefer to have the plot as a vector graphic in my document.

Comment: Questions about Inkscape are probably better asked on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com. I would btw not expect to get a huge decrease in filesize from the concept you describe, unless many points have the precise *same* coordinates and are hence removed *completely*. Else, you end up with as many points as you had before, those just have different shapes.

Comment: Can you share an example file, please? It may be possible to reduce the size, but we'd need to know what's in the file before we can give a qualified answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to keep all the data points as vector graphics, its unlikely you'll be able to reduce the file size.

While not ideal, one potential option is to rasterize only the data points created by `ax.scatter`, and leave the axes, labels, titles, etc. all as vector elements on your figure. This can dramatically reduce the file size, and if you set the dpi high enough, you probably won't lose any useful information from the plot.

You can do this by setting `rasterized=True` when calling `ax.scatter`.

You can then control the dpi of the rasterized elements using `dpi=300` (or whatever dpi you want) when you `fig.savefig`.

Consider the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figV, axesV = plt.subplots(nrows=10, ncols=5)
figR, axesR = plt.subplots(nrows=10, ncols=5)

for ax in figV.axes:
    ax.scatter(range(3000), range(3000))
for ax in figR.axes:
    ax.scatter(range(3000), range(3000), rasterized=True)

figV.savefig('bigscatterV.svg')
figR.savefig('bigscatterR.svg', dpi=300)
```

`bigscatterV.svg` has a file size of 16MB, while `bigscatterR.svg` has a file size of only 250KB.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really reduces the filesize significantly and is exactly what I want to have.
However, now I just came across a new problem. My svg file is now about 4 MB, which is good. But I have to convert the svg file into an emf file before importing it into Word (there is a stupid bug in Word which causes it to be stuck in a save loop when using svg files) - and the emf file grows again to 60 MB after performing the converting with inkscape. Do you have an idea why this is happening? Same thing happens when I output eps files with matplotlib directly.

Comment: No idea, sorry, I rarely use word/inkscape. what about using a `pdf` file?

Comment: Yes the pdf file is also quite small (about 2 MB) and of good quality. But there is some problem with Word again - Word just produces a preview of the pdf when inserting it as a image (probably jpg). But well, that's just some stupid Word problem again. I should probably just switch to LaTeX...but thanks anyways, your tip with the rasterizing is really helpful!